# Apache re-write URL path that doesn't exist

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

We currently have a website with a URL structure as follows:

https://www.example.com/en_CA/homepage/page1.html

https://www.example.com/en_CA/homepage/page2.html

We need to shorten the URL to:

https://www.example.com/page1.html

https://www.example.com/page2.html

We have tried using the following rewrite rules and conditions:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en_CA/homepage/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /en_CA/homepage/$1 [P]
```

The problem we have is that we get a 404 because the shorter URL doesn't exist. I think the solution needs to also involve AliasMatch to set up an alias for that URL but I'm not sure how to go about that.

I've tried:

```
AliasMatch ^/[^/]*/(.*) /en_CA/homepage/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en_CA/homepage/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /en_CA/homepage/$1 [PT]
```

But this doesn't work.

The website is build using Adobe AEM so we need to ensure that AEM only ever receives the long URL.

Thanks

Russell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `AliasMatch`, I think, you want to access the url https://www.example.com/en_CA/homepage/page1.html from https://www.example.com/page1.html, and the same to the other one. Please let me know if I am wrong.
Try this, let me know if it works:

> Please read the comments (text after # symbol) carefully

```
# Add this to your root .htaccess file i.e the public_html, htdocs, etc. or use RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On # Do not use this two times in one .htaccess file, be sure you don't have any other directories other than /en_CA/homepage/ in your root dir, or use the RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dirname/$1 [L] for every dir.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/en_CA/homepage/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en_CA/homepage/$1 [L]
```

I am sure the above will work.

Follow the same to other folders.

I will add something later to hide the folder containing it.

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a more generic way to do this if there are say 100 pages? The idea is to hide the /en_CA/homepage/ part for the user completely but it has to be there when the request hits the server. Thanks

Comment: I will add something new to my answer for sure. :)

Comment: Check it out now, I will add the rules to block access to the real folder later on, when I find out about that.

Comment: You are welcome. And also, I will update this answer whenever I have better suggestions.